# How do i rename the "Show Filterbar" / "Hide Filterbar" Button Text of a Filterbar?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Working with the sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar.
This is what ive tried so far:

```
onInit():
var oFilterbar = this.getView().byId("filterBar");
            oFilterbar._oHideShowButton.setProperty("text", "Anzeigen");
            oFilterbar._oHideShowButton.setAggregation("tooltip", "Anzeigen");
```

This does rename the button... until u press it. Then its back to "Hide Filter Bar" and "Show Filter Bar".

also onInit():

```
oFilterbar.addEventDelegate({
                onclick: (oEvent) => {
                    if(oEvent.target.id.includes("btnShowHide")) {
                            oFilterbar._oHideShowButton.setProperty("text", "Anzeigen");
                            oFilterbar._oHideShowButton.setAggregation("tooltip", "Anzeigen");
                    }
                  },
              });
```

This one is being called everytime u press the Show/Hide Button but doesnt do anything. Im guessing that is because the original button renaming event happens after.

Thankful for any ideas